# Can I use capital losses to offset income tax in the UK?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

In the US, I am aware of the term called ‘tax loss harvesting’ where capital losses can be used to offset up to $3000 income. Is there a similar method in the UK to do this?

Comment: tax loss harvesting is not _just_ to deduct from regular income - it can also be used to reduce _capital gains_ in a tax year

Answer (score 4):

No. You can only carry the losses forward to offset against future capital gains.

It's hard to find a definitive statement of a negative, but [this page](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/losses) from HMRC is pretty clear what you can do with losses and it doesn't include deducting them from income.